# How do I get to the Badge Machine?

Tags: mario-sonic-london-2012

I have earned two tickets for the Badge Machine by playing various parts of the game.

Where is the Badge Machine? Do I need to unlock it somehow? How do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little tricky to find (they hid it without any obvious pointer.) It is unlocked right away, but you have to look for it.

From the main selection screen, go into "Record Log".

From there, select "Collection".

In the Collection menu, there is the option to use your tickets at the Badge Machine. :)

Answer (score 1):

First go to the main menu 
Next go to record log 
Finally when you are in record log touché the badge machine option and start spending some tickets